# Anyone has experience on Elasticsearch shadow replica?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am now investigating the elasticsearch shadow replica usage in our ES cluster.

I would like to know if any one/team already has experience on shadow replica?

I am most interested in the performance (both indexing and searching) and reliability of shadow replica.

Comment: What's the use case and why do you think you need shadow replicas?

Comment: I am going to deploy ES on Azure VM scale sets to leverage the auto-scale functionality. To enable auto-scale, shadow replica will be best option, since when ES nodes scale out, it will take short time to finish the shard re-balance across nodes.

Comment: This is not the intended use case for shadow replicas... Why do you think it will take short time to re-balance? Primary shards **will still be moved across the wire**. Yes, replicas will not be moved (because there is no physical replica on disks). What you want is pretty much the same thing as using 0 replicas for your indices.

Comment: So, what is the right scenario to use shadow replica?

Comment: If you have a file system that creates copies of the data itself in which case there is no need for ES to create its own copies as well. Basically, the replication is handled by the OS and the file system.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I am going to use Azure File storage, which is a service that offers file shares in the cloud using the standard SMB protocol, together with VM scale sets. I think shadow replica is best option for combination of VM scale sets (with auto-scale) and Azure File storage (distributed shared file system). But seems so far, shadow replica is not widely used.

Comment: This sounds interesting. There is no point in having duplicated data (replicas) on a shared file system. If it fails, then all copies will fail. In this case, yes, it should be ok to use shadow replicas. And do try it out, don't let you discouraged by low adoption, the use cases are not that common and that's the reason. I can guarantee that it works.

Comment: Shared storage is generally not advisable for storing Elasticsearch shard data, due to the low latency that it provides. And Elasticsearch relies on having as much as possible IOPS and the storage disks to be as close as possible to the machine holding the node. Preferably and ideally, an ES node should use SSD disks that are local (inside) the node's physical machine.